# Why can dereferenced pointers with postfix operators be expressed with parenthesis and still get the previous dereferenced value?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I do not understand the order of precedence here.  Given:

```
*(p++)
```

Here is what I thought would happen:

```
(p++)
```

then

```
*p
```

Why isn't the address of `p` incremented first, then dereferenced, since the postfix is in the parenthesis?

```
*(p++)
```

Why isn't the address incremented and then dereferenced *because of the parenthesis*.

`*p++` does not appear to be the same as `*(p++)`, but they are the same.

Comment: That is the fastest downvote I have ever seen.  How come?

Comment: Good question, I'd even suggest it for C/C++ FAQ, if possible. Maybe one should also add the not-so-obvious difference between `*(p++)` and `*(p+1)`.

Comment: @Frunsi Those are different, aren't they?  I thought they were.

Comment: Yes, but all in all, it looks as if there is much confusion about postfix operators in parenthesis. So, IMHO it is worth an FAQ entry ;)

Comment: This is a good question. That's why it's been asked a million times.

Comment: You're confusing precedence, evaluation order and evaluation result.

Comment: @johnny: Yes, that's what he's saying.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no cause for such understatements.

Answer (score 6):

In `*(p++)`, the value of `p` is incremented by the `p++`, but the result of `p++` is the value before the increment, and the `*` applies to the value before the increment.  The parentheses are superfluous — arguably the mark of someone unsure of the language.

If you want to dereference the incremented value, you'd pre-increment:

```
*(++p)
*++p
```

Note that if you want to increment what `p` points at, you use:

```
(*p)++
++*p
++(*p)
```

The last two are the same, just spelled differently.  The parentheses are necessary in the first of these three; `*p++` is `*(p++)` and not `(*p)++`.

Comment: Oh, I see it is doing the ++ first but returning the previous value like any other time with the postfix.  I think I had in my head that somehow p++ was the same as p+1 because the p++ is in parenthesis.  Simply *p++ makes perfect sense, but when they put the () in, I lost my mind.

Answer (score 2):

It is not about the order of precedence. It is about how postfix increment works.

What happens in p++ (assuming p is an `int*` for this simple example) is:

```
int* tmp = p; 
p = p + 1; 
return tmp;
```

so you are dereferencing the original value of p.